# Display only maximum value in query with column meno - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

As mentioned in the title I want to display only row with maximum number, for this case it´s number 4 and nothing less.

```
select divak.MENO,count(divak.MENO)
    from sledovanost
    natural join tv_stanice
    natural join divak
    group by divak.meno
    order by count(divak.MENO)desc;
```

[My query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp18W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by a `having`-clause, in which you compare each `MENO` count with the maximum `MENO` count (retrieved by a subquery):

```
select divak.MENO,count(divak.MENO)
    from sledovanost
    natural join tv_stanice
    natural join divak
    group by divak.meno
    having count(divak.MENO) = (
      select (max(count(divak.MENO))
      from sledovanost
      natural join tv_stanice
      natural join divak
      group by divak.meno)
```

BTW: I'd change the query to `join .. ON ..` syntax; `natural join`, which connects tables on equally named attributes, bears the danger of "unintended connections" whenever the db schema changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `natural join`.  It uses the names of the columns to match tables, and doesn't show the names in the query.  It is a bug waiting to happen.  Use `USING` or `ON`.

In Oracle, you would normally do this using `row_number()` or `rank()` depending on whether or not you wanted duplicates:

```
with t as (<your query here but name the second column>)
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```